# node.js link routes each other

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a little bit problem with the routes of node.js  .
I managed these routes(get and post) in the folder called routes.
Now I'd like to call from one route an other route in a different file .
How can I do?

Comment: using _res.redirect('/path')_ . you can move to another route

Answer (score 2):

Using res.redirect you can move to another route.
here is an Example code

```
router.get('/abc', function(req, res){
 ....
 res.redirect('/efg');
}
```

and in your app.js define file path for the route like

```
var efg= require('./path-to-efg');
app.use('/', efg);
```